# Use of CONCAT operator in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a search form where I could search by Name:

```
if($v=$_POST['Name']){
     $sql.=" AND CONCAT(' ',Name) LIKE '% $v%'";
     }
if($v=$_POST['PriceU']){
     $sql.=" AND Price BETWEEN '$_POST[PriceF]' AND '$_POST[PriceU]'";
     }
if($v=$_POST['RateU']) {
    $sql.=" AND Rate BETWEEN '$_POST[RateF]' AND '$_POST[RateU]'";
    }
if($v=$_POST['Cat']) {
    $sql.=" AND Category='$_POST[Cat]' ";
}

$resm=mysql_query ("SELECT * from members WHERE Level='$_GET[level]' $sql  Order By Name");
```

Just to understand, I echoed out '$resm'. When I search with the name Toyota this is the query that is generated:

```
SELECT * FROM members
WHERE Level='2' AND
      CONCAT(' ',Name) LIKE '% Toyota%'
ORDER BY Name.
```

BUt my problem is what is the use of `CONCAT(' ',Name)` here? I thought it should work even when it is without `CONCAT`. That is

```
if($v=$_POST['Name']){
  $sql.=" AND (' ',Name) LIKE '% $v%'";
```

Then the SQL generated is

```
SELECT * from members WHERE Level='2' AND Name LIKE '% Toyota%' Order By Name
```

But this doesn't output anything. Why is that? What's wrong with this query and what's the effect `CONCAT` is having?

Comment: Why are you prepending a space to 'Name'?

Comment: What's wrong with `'%Toyota%'` without a space to match against?

Comment: Terrible code, no prepared statements, no input check. Hello SQL injection.

Answer (score 4):

`CONCAT(' ', Name)` prepends a space to the column values. In combination with

```
LIKE '% Toyota%'
```

this prevents finding *Toyota* in the middle of a word, but allows finding it at the start of the field.

Answer (score 0):

`CONCAT()` accepts two or more strings as parameters and combines them by appending them after each other. For example, `CONCAT('hel', 'lo')` returns `hello`. What you are doing is checking if the `Name` column would match the keyword if both of them were prepended by a space. It's unclear why, but my guess is trying to prevent matching only part of a word, such as matching `Kia` with `Nokia`. This approach does have a weakness, as it would still match words with extra letters in the end - searching for `Audi` would return `Audioslave` and so on.

Comment: why doesn't `if($v=$_POST['Name']){
  $sql.=" AND Name LIKE '% $v%'";
  }`this work?

Comment: But when I use `if($v=$_POST['Name']){
  $sql.=" AND Name LIKE '$v%'";
  }` it works.Why is this ?

Comment: The first one doesn't work because it only finds rows where `Name` has a space right in front of it, for example `" toyota"`. The latter one finds rows that start with your search term with nothing in front of it.

Comment: Thanks.Didn't know that space is also taken in account